# Is there a way to prevent pandas AttributeError? Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to be able to create a bunch of conditions than can be optionally evaluated based on a user input. However, the data frame will not always have the same columns or use every single condition. Let's say you have spending information and have built conditions for 4 columns. However, a user is only able to provide three columns. How can you store a set of data conditions and call them without running into issues?

Code conditions created for expected input:

| Date | Amount | Category | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

However, user is only able to provide the below information

| Date | Amount | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11-01-2022 | 190 | bill |
| 11-01-2022 | 50 | grocery |
| 11-01-2022 | 55 | shopping |
| 12-01-2022 | 10 | grocery |
| 12-01-2022 | 80 | bill |
| 12-01-2022 | 90 | grocery |

Which will lead to an AttributeError. Example below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    'Date' : ['11-01-2022', '11-01-2022', '11-01-2022', '12-01-2022', '12-01-2022', '12-01-2022'],
    'Amount' : [190, 50, 55, 10, 80, 90],
    'Category' : ['bill', 'grocery', 'shopping', 'grocery', 'bill', 'grocery']
    } 
)

conditions = {
    'december_amount_under_20' : (df.Date== 'Dec') & (df.Amount > 20), # works
    'year_2022' : df.Year == 2022 # AttributeError
}
```

Comment: You could just loop over your conditions and try each one, catching AttributeErrors and moving on.

Comment: Note that `&` is `bitwise and`. Do you really mean that?

Comment: @buran - Probably yes, the conditions return two boolean series and a bitwise and acts like a regular `and` in an `if` statement in this context. The `# works` comment is a lie by the way. For the example dataset that also raises an `AttributeError`.

Comment: @Maurice - _probably yes..._ - that is exactly my point. It may produce the expected result in this particular case, but it's very likely that OP *thinks* this is `and` - quite common confusion and get surprised in other cases. My note is irrelevant to his problem right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the `AttributeError` because pandas evaluates *all* conditions as soon as the dictionary is created. Your `#works` comment is a bit misleading because you'll also get an `AttributeError` for that one since Month doesn't exist in the sample dataset.

Writing things like `df.Amount >= 20` causes a new pandas Series to be created that contains `True` or `False` for each row in the original dataframe indicating if it fulfills the condition or not.

```py
> (df.Amount >= 20)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
Name: Amount, dtype: bool
> type(df.Amount >= 20)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

We want to delay *executing* the filter until we actually try to filter the records. We can achieve that for example by putting them into anonymous functions (lambda).

```py
import typing # Because type annotations are helpful

# By putting the conditions in anonymous functions (lambda) we delay their evaluation
conditions: typing.Dict[str, typing.Callable[[pd.DataFrame], pd.Series]] = {
    "amount_greater_40": lambda df: df.Amount > 40,
    "december_amount_under_20": lambda df: (df.Month == "Dec") & (df.Amount > 20),
    "year_2022": lambda df: df.Year == 2022,
}
```

**Note**: I've added the `amount_greater_40` condition here so I'd see a result in my tests.

We can then write a small helper function that tells us if a condition can be applied to a dataframe:

```py
def is_condition_applicable(
    dataframe: pd.DataFrame, filter_fn: typing.Callable[[pd.DataFrame], pd.Series]
) -> bool:
    """Returns true if a condition function is applicable, otherwise false."""
    try:
        # We don't want to filter the whole dataframe yet, that would be
        # inefficient. By focussing on the header we check if the required
        # columns exist.
        just_headers = dataframe.head(0)
        filter_fn(just_headers)
        return True
    except AttributeError:
        return False
```

Using this function we can then filter all conditions to the ones that are applicable for a given dataframe:

```py
applicable_conditions = {
    name: condition
    for name, condition in conditions.items()
    if is_condition_applicable(df, condition)
}
```

Here's an example of applying all applicable conditions:

```py
for condition_name, condition_fn in applicable_conditions.items():
    print(f"Results for the condition {condition_name}")
    print(df[condition_fn(df)])
```

For your example dataset this is the output:

```
$ python so_multifilter.py
Results for the condition amount_greater_40
         Date  Amount  Category
0  11-01-2022     190      bill
1  11-01-2022      50   grocery
2  11-01-2022      55  shopping
4  12-01-2022      80      bill
5  12-01-2022      90   grocery
```